# Issue in pagination in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I want to do pagination in backbone. I have a selectbox and when I click on it I want it to show sepcific number of data.

```
<div class="results right" >
          <form>
            <label for="results">Results pr. page</label>
            <select name="results" id="ShowSelect">
              <option value="25" >25</option>
              <option value="50" >50</option>
              <option value="100" >100</option>
              <option value="500" >500</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Model

```
defaults : {
                id : null,
                created : null,
                timestamp : null


            },

parse : function(response){
                response.id = response._id.$oid;
                response.created = response.created.$date;
                response.timestamp = response.timestamp.$date;

                return response;
            },
```

This is my collection:

```
pagination : function(perPage, page) {
                page = page - 1;
                var collection = this;
                collection = _(collection.rest(perPage * page));
                collection = _(collection.first(perPage));
                return collection.map( function(model) {
                    return model.toJSON();
                });
            },
```

and this is my view in a separate file: (uncompleted)

```
     events : {

                            "change #messageSelect" : "changedGroup",

                        },

       changedGroup : function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("selector changed");
                        this.currentPage = 1;
                        this.selectedGroupId = $("#messageSelect :selected").attr("value");
                        console.log("id of select is", this.selectedGroupId);

                        //Resets current groups when changed.
                        this.currentGroup = this.collection.get(this.selectedGroupId);
                    },

renderRecentList : function(groupID, pageToLoad) {
                    var banPage = pageToLoad || this.currentBansPage ;
                    console.log("Load page", banPage);
                    this.selectedGroup = this.collection.get(groupID);
                }
```

To be honset, I do not know how to evaluate max page in view. What I did is that I get the id of selector when the user click on it (the number of data I want to load e.g. 100, 50 etc) and created another function for evaluating max page to load. but how can I get the number of data

```
 var maxPages = Math.ceil(? / this.pageSize);
                        console.log("max", maxPages);
                        var pageToLoad = this.currentPage + 1;
                        console.log("load me page", pageToLoad);
                        if(pageToLoad <= maxPages) this.renderRecentList(this.selectedGroupId, pageToLoad);
                        else{
                            console.log("no more pages to load");
                            this.setGlobalMessage("no more pages to load", "information");
                        }
                        return this;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to do this on the server side. Load only the items you want to show and if the parameters change create a new request.

So the steps:

1. Create a service that recives the per page and page number parameters and returns only the corresponding items.
2. When the user first enter this page do a request with the default parameters and render the items.
3. When the user changes the page or the items per page do a new request and render the items that came from the server.